# After ssl implementation in cakephp 3 return $this->redirect() stop working

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have implemented the below code for `ssl` implementation, but after that my redirect is no longer working:

Here is my code:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class WidgetsController extends AppController
{

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Security', ['blackHoleCallback' => 'forceSSL']);
}

public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{

        $this->Security->requireSecure();

}


public function testRedirect()
{

        **$this->redirect("/controller/Somewhere");**

}

public function forceSSL()
{
    return $this->redirect('https://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->request->getRequestTarget());
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Provide details on what you are doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: thanks, found the problem, I just need to put  $this->Security->setConfig('unlockedActions', ['testRedirect']);  below the  $this->Security->requireSecure(); and it will redirect  $this->redirect("/controller/Somewhere");